# Laravel 4 passing Controller $this to ServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel-4, this, service-provider

I want to pass `$this` from my **Controller** to my **Service Provider** so I can use it with my custom class. That way, I can reference back to my controller and output the success.

**Controller**

```
function Foo(){

    //$this is defined
    MyFacade::Bar($input);

}

function success(){

     return var_dump('Succes!');

}
```

**Service Provider**

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\Filesystem;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as  IlluminateServiceProvider;
use App\Libraries\Extensions\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class FilesystemServiceProvider extends IlluminateServiceProvider {

   public function register()
        { 
            $this->app->bind('files', function(){

               return new Filesystem($this);

            });    
    }
}
```

**Custom Class**

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries\Extensions\Filesystem;

use \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem as IlluminateFilesystem;

class Filesystem extends IlluminateFilesystem {

protected $listener;

    public function __construct($listener)
    {

        $this->listener = $listener;

    }

   function Bar($input){
     //Some code
     return $this->listener->Success();
   }
```

With this code I'm getting `Call to undefined method App\Libraries\Extensions\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::Success()`.

I believe that my `Service Provider $this` is passed instead of my `Controller $this`.

How can I pass my Controller `$this` to my Service Provider so I can just call `MyFacade::Bar($input)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to pass $this from my Controller to my Service Provider so I
>   can use it with my custom class. That way, I can reference back to my
>   controller and output the success.

That is a terrible idea, and you'll have trouble making it work anyway.

Your Filesystem class should have no knowledge of your controller class. Passing in $this and trying to get File to do your controller's work is not the way to do it. It should just do its 'file' stuff, and then return an appropriate response.

**Controller**

```
function Foo(){

    if (MyFacade::Bar($input))
    { 
        // Success
    }
    else
    {
        // Fail
    }

}
```

**Custom Class**

```
function Bar($input){
     //Some code
     return true; // or false
   }
```